# QGIS 3.22.5, 3.22.10, and 3.26.2 keep crashing when using GEOTIFFS

Tags: crash, qgis, geotiff

I'm uploading NAIP GEOTIFFS that I got from the USDA website. They are TIFFS with the coordinate system imbedded. They are loading correctly but the QGIS crashes when I try to get into the properties of the image layer. I would like to make some of them transparent. Originally this happened in version 3.22.5. Then I installed 3.22.10 and 3.26.2 and it still happens. Could it be related to my profile or plug-ins? Wonder if I should uninstall my plugins and then try. Uninstalling plug-ins would just be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Update-Took the plunge and unloaded all my plug-ins. This worked. I think I had some weird plug-ins that weren't working properly. So problem solved.